# Take existing linux install and make it pxeboot

Tags: pxe-boot, ramdisk

Is there any way I can take an existing install of debian that I have on a usb drive and make it so I can pxeboot it as a ramdisk image? Almost everything I find online is about making a image boot over nfs but I need it to just boot as a ramdisk image.

I have been able to make a new image boot without any problems by using [this guide](http://www.evanjones.ca/software/pxeimager-scratch.html) but I already have a installed system that has all the extra software and drivers I need so I would like to use that.

What I have done so far is make make a new image like it says at the bottom of the guide and copied over all the files from the usb drive. The only file I changed is fstab so it was like the one in the guild but when I try and boot it I get an error that says "Kernel panic - not syncing: No init found. Try passing init= option to kernel."

Thanks